# Moving from ISC DHCPd to Windows Server 2008 R2 DHCP

Tags: linux, windows, dhcp, dhcp-server

I currently have a Linux server running ISC DHCPd and I'd like to eliminate this server and move to a Windows DHCP server. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to accomplish this or if someone could recommend some best practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DNS servers in Windows Server 2003 and 2008 (R2) are capable of being configured textually using the `netsh` command. I'm not aware of any projects to parse the ISC DHCPd configuration file and output the equivalent `netsh` commands but it ought to be reasonably easy. (I see where some as [written a REXX script to convert the other direction](http://support.menandmice.com/jforum/posts/list/177.page), but that's probably of limited utility to you.)

[Some background on `netsh`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725935(WS.10).aspx) should be able to get you started.

Comment: +1, I helped our Unix guy with going the other direction: MS DHCP to ISC DHCP. I needed to use `netsh` to export our config into a parseable form, and he ran that through a script he wrote to generate an ISC version. Worked pretty good.